# Как при клике вне меню закрыть его?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при клике вне меню закрыть его?

```js
const btnMenu = document.querySelector('.menu__btn')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu__list')
const toggleMenu = function () {
    menu.classList.toggle('open')
}

btnMenu.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    toggleMenu()
})

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const target = e.target
    const its_menu = target == menu || menu.contains(target)
    const its_btnMenu = target == btnMenu
    const menu_is_active = menu.classList.contains('open')

    if (!its_menu && !its_btnMenu && menu_is_active) {
        toggleMenu()
    }
})
```

```css
.hamburger-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#menu__toggle {
  display: block;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__list {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

// .open {
//  visibility: visible;
//  left: 0;
// }
.menu__btn {
  // display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: calc(100% - 35px);
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  // @include flex($horizontal:flex-end);
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__list {
  // display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /*    visibility: hidden; */
  top: 0px;
  left: -100%;
  // left: 20px;
  width: 292px;
  // padding: 80px 0;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  //  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: 14px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu__list .open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 29px 50px 21px 35px;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: $fontFamilyM;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  background: #333333;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #3b3b3b;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__item-last::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 292px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #333333;
}

.menu__link:active {
  color: $violetColor;
}

.menu__item:active .menu__link::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu__link::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 53px;
  background: $violetColor;
  left: 0px;
  top: calc((100% - 53px) / 2);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="menu__btn menu__btn--active" for="menu__toggle">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>

                    <ul class="menu__list">
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Overview</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">About Fork</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Buying Options</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item menu__item-last">
                            <a class="menu__link" href="#">Support</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии кнопок меню, меню не должно закрываться? Тогда, может быть, так:

```
   const btnMenu = document.querySelector('.menu__btn');
        const menu = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
        const menuToggle = document.querySelector('#menu__toggle');

   /*     const toggleMenu = function () {
             menu.classList.toggle('open');
        } */

       btnMenu.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            toggleMenu()
        }) 

        function onDocumentClick(e) {
            const target = e.target
            const its_menu = target == menu || menu.contains(target)
            console.log(`its_menu =${its_menu} ${menu.contains(target)}`);
            const its_btnMenu = target == btnMenu
            const menu_is_active = menuToggle.checked//menu.classList.contains('open')
            if (!its_menu && !its_btnMenu && menu_is_active && target !=menuToggle) {
                //toggleMenu();
                menuToggle.checked = false;
            }

        }
       document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сработало))))